# Select last observation per group

Tags: python, pandas

Someone asked to select the first observation per group in pandas df, I am interested in both first and last, and I don't know an efficient way of doing it except writing a for loop.

I am going to modify his example to tell you what I am looking for
basically there is a df like this:

```
group_id 
1          
1        
1        
2        
2        
2        
3        
3        
3
```

I would like to have a variable that indicates the last observation in a group:

```
group_id indicator
1        0  
1        0
1        1
2        0
2        0
2        1
3        0
3        0
3        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`pandas.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), you can do something like:

```
df['group_indicator'] = df.group_id != df.group_id.shift(-1)
```

(or

```
df['group_indicator'] = (df.group_id != df.group_id.shift(-1)).astype(int)
```

if it's actually important for you to have it as an integer.)

---

**Note:**

1. for large datasets, this should be much faster than list comprehension (not to mention loops).
2. As Alexander notes, this assumes the DataFrame is sorted as it is in the example.

Comment: A great alternative, but requires the dataframe to first be sorted by the `group_id` (as it is in this example).

Answer (score 1):

First, we'll create a list of the index locations containing the last element of each group.  You can see the elements of each group as follows:

```
>>> df.groupby('group_id').groups
{1: [0, 1, 2], 2: [3, 4, 5], 3: [6, 7, 8]}
```

We use a list comprehension to extract the last index location (`idx[-1]`) of each of these group index values.

We assign the indicator to the dataframe by using a list comprehension and a ternary operator (i.e. 1 if condition else 0), iterating across each element in the index and checking if it is in the `idx_last_group` list.

```
idx_last_group = [idx[-1] for idx in df.groupby('group_id').groups.values()]
df['indicator'] = [1 if idx in idx_last_group else 0 for idx in df.index]

>>> df
   group_id  indicator
0         1          0
1         1          0
2         1          1
3         2          0
4         2          0
5         2          1
6         3          0
7         3          0
8         3          1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.tail`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html) method:

```
df=df.groupby('group_id').tail(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `groupby` the 'id' and call `nth(-1)` to get the last entry for each group, then use this to mask the df and set the 'indicator' to `1` and then the rest with `0` using `fillna`:

```
In [21]:
df.loc[df.groupby('group_id')['group_id'].nth(-1).index,'indicator'] = 1
df['indicator'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df

Out[21]:
   group_id  indicator
0         1          0
1         1          0
2         1          1
3         2          0
4         2          0
5         2          1
6         3          0
7         3          0
8         3          1
```

Here is the output from the `groupby`:

```
In [22]:
df.groupby('group_id')['group_id'].nth(-1)

Out[22]:
2    1
5    2
8    3
Name: group_id, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

One line:

```
data['indicator'] = (data.groupby('group_id').cumcount()==data.groupby('group_id')['any_other_column'].transform('size') -1 ).astype(int)`
```

What we do is check if the cumulative count (which returns a vector the same size as the dataframe) is equal to the "size of the group - 1" which we calculate using transform so it also returns a vector the same size as the dataframe.

We need to use some other column for the transform because it won't let you transform the `.groupby()` variable but this can literally any other column and it won't be affected since its only used in calculating the new indicator. Use `.astype(int)` to make it a binary and done.